# ExecutorService inside an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, executorservice

I'd like to execute a lot of (100-1000) short-running tasks in the background, and show a `Dialog` to the user until all the tasks are finished.

I'm doing this by using `ExecutorService` inside an `AsyncTask`:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // a collection of objects to pass to my Callables
    private Collection<MyObject> objects;

    private ExecutorService executor;
    private List<Future<MyObject>> futures;

    public MyTask(Collection<MyObject> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        futures = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // submitting the tasks
        for(MyObject object : objects) {
            futures.add(executor.submit(new MyCallable(object)));
        }

        // scheduling the executor for shutdown
        executor.shutdown();

        // showing the Dialog
        showLoadingDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // performing the blocking operation in doInBackground()
        // and shutting down the executor when the tasks are finished,
        // or timeout is reached
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        for(Future<MyObject> future : futures) {
            // processing the result
        }

        // dismissing the Dialog
        dismissLoadingDialog();
    }
}
```

This was the best solution i could come up with.

My question is: **Is this a bad approach?**

If so, why? I'd also appreciate any advice on how to do this properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Executing 100 threads on a limited device, mobile phone? really?

Comment: Yeah, i guess i should use a thread pool with a fixed size. Edited my code. The question is still valid. Basically i'd like to execute large number of tasks in the background while showing a `Dialog` and know the result of every task after all of them finished or a timeout is reached. I have not seen anyone else using executors inside an `AsyncTask`, that's why i'm not sure if it's a good approach.